# goto not working with ?: operator in C

Tags: c, conditional-operator, goto

For learning purposes, I wrote the following code snippet:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  for(int j = 0;j<5;j++)        
  {
    //(i==j && i==3)? (goto found) : printf("stya here\n");        
    if(i==j && i==3){goto found;} else {printf("stay here\n");}
  }
}

found:
  printf("yes I am here");
```

But I wondered when I discovered the omitted statement inside the inner loop not gives error and now I am confused about if-else is not always replaceable with `?:` operator. What is the fact here? Why does the commented statement give an error?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxbyfc2c

Comment: @Mat why did you edited c with V?

Comment: Sorry, typo. You had `c`, I wanted to replace with `C` but slipped. You can edit your own post btw, you could have fixed that yourself.

Comment: I forget. But I click on the edit then I saw C, not c...and I saved edits... you okay Mat??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `?:` operator is not replacement for `if`. It works only for expressions: `condition ? expr1 : expr2` where both sub-expressions `expr1` and `expr2` are of the same type (and the whole expression then is of the same type).

`goto` is not expression, it is a statement.

Answer (score 3):

I am not well versed enough in C to explain why this doesn't work syntactically, but in the sense of intent the ?: ternary operator form is intended as a conditional expression (yields a result), not as a control flow mechanism. Using the if statement you can choose a value for a variable or change the flow of the application. 
e.g.

```
//Change flow

if(x ==0)
{
   //do this
} 
else
{
 //goto some label
}
```

or

```
//Change value
    if(x == 0)
    {
      y = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      y = 2;
    }
```

The ternary is only intended for the second case, as a conditional expression 
i.e.

```
y = (x ==0) ? 1 :2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, what you're trying to do with goto and the ternary operator is possible if your compiler support the extension [Statement Expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs), as it's name said, this extension allow you to write statements inside an expression or sub-expressions, just like this:

```
(rand() % 2) ? ({goto lbl1;}) : ({goto lbl2;});
```

Using these statements can be very useful (mostly to optimize macros) but often lead to very dirty code, just like the example i gave :)

So to complement the other answers i'll say that it's not possible in C99/11 without extension but most of the recent compiler support a bunch of extension that allows you to do non-standard cool things.

Answer (score 1):

What would be the result of "goto found" expression? I don't know, neither does the compiler, so the result of `?` expression cannot be determined, hence the error.

Comment: Is "goto found" an expression?

Comment: @alaminhosain: He does see the label. The question is what the result of the expression would be. For example, consider: `int p; p = (i==j && i==3)? (goto found) : printf("stya here\n");`. It's clear what value `p` has on the `printf` side. But value does `p` have on the `goto` side?! That's what the compiler can't figure out.

Comment: @Okay, then why this is working where both the functions are void  `(i==j && i==3)? fun1() : fun2();`

Comment: If your functions are declared `void fun1()` it won't work either.

Comment: @tristopia, Is there any modification with this in c++, because I just seen worked that in my Bloodshed/DevC++ compiler.

Comment: void functions are OK to use, because they return void value (i.e. no value), again I ask you what value should `goto found` expression _return_ to be the result of `?` expression

Comment: You will at least get a warning. Warnings are not meant to be ignored. Always compile we the highest warning level and always try to understand and remove them.

Comment: @panda-34, I am not sure but whatever printf() returns in the found label that could be...

Answer (score 1):

In general, the `?:` operator is no replacement for a classic `if() ... else() ...`. It might be used as such if both operators (and the condition) are values or expressions returning a value. You can't use them with statements like `goto`, `break` or `continue`.

The following would be possible:

```
condition ? dothis() : dothat(); // there's no assignment, but it's still valid
var = condition ? dothis() : othervar;
condition ? (var=4, othervar=3) : (somevar = 1);
```

But you can't include anything that's not an expression (i.e. nothing not having some value or result):

```
condition ? continue : break; // statements letting the execution continue somewhere else
condition ? {var = 4; othervar = 3;} : dothat(); // trying to inline scopes/multiple exressions
var = condition ? while(var) {var--;} : 5; // similar, inlining a complete loop
```

These last examples can be done, but they'd require you to use `if()` or function bodys to call:

```
if (condition) continue; else break;
condition ? (var = 4, var = 3) : dothat();
var = condition ? dotheloop(var) : 5; // ok, this could be 'var = condition ? 0 : 5;' but... example code
```

Comment: why not, condition? dothis():printf("print"); works? but,      condition? printf("print1") : printf("print2"); works?

Comment: Actually, both should work, but to be honest in latter case I'd prefer doing `printf(condition ? "print1" : "print2");`.