# Replacement for goto in switch case

Tags: c, switch-statement, goto

I have written this code to perform multiple mathematical operation, with main menu to select the operation, and repeat it until you want and revert back to main menu. I have looped it using switch case and go-to. I want to replace the go-to, and want suggestions regarding how can I make it function in same way without using go-to.
Thank you.

```
//I want the program of be infinite until you want to exit.Thus I used goto to continuously loop it back to either main menu or the mathematical operation you are in. 
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int a,b,i,num,n;
char rep;
void main (void)

{
//main menu-(main:-for goto function)
main:
{
printf("\nMAIN MENU\n\n1. Factorial\n2. Sum\n3. Odd/Even\n4. Prime Number\n5. Multiplication\n6. Exit\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
}
switch (n)
{
    case 1:
        {
            fact:
            {
            printf("Number- ");
            scanf("%d", &num);
            a=1;
        for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
        {
            a=a*i;
            continue;
        }
        printf("\nFactorial of %d= %d\n\n", num, a);

//This is how I loop it back to main menu or for repeating the mathematical operation using combination of conditional operators and goto.
        printf("Repeat? y/n- ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &rep);
        (rep=='y')?({goto fact;}):({goto main;});
        }
        }
    case 2:
        {
            sum:
            {
                a=0;
            printf("Value of repetitions- ");
            scanf("%d", &num);
            printf("Enter Digits to sum:\n");

            for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &b);
                printf("+ ");
                a=a+b;
                continue;
            }
            printf("\nThe Sum of Digits= %d\n\n", a);
            printf("Repeat? y/n- ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", &rep);
            (rep=='y')?({goto sum;}):({goto main;});
            }
        }

    case 3:
        {
            oe:
            {
                printf("Enter a Number- ");
                scanf("%d", &a);
                (a%2==0)?(printf("\n%d is an Even Number\n",a)):(printf("\n%d is an Odd number\n", a));
            printf("\nRepeat? y/n- ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", &rep);
            (rep=='y')?({goto oe;}):({goto main;});
            }
        }
    case 4:
        {
            prime:
                {
                    printf("\nEnter a Number- ");
                    scanf("%d",&num);
                    if(num==2)
                        printf("\n\n%d is a Prime Number\n\n", num);

                    for(i=2;i<=num-1;i++)
                    {

                        (num%i==0)?({printf("\n\n%d is Not a Prime Number.\n\n", num);break;}):({printf("\n\n%d is a Prime Number\n\n", num);break;});

                    }

                    printf("\nRepeat? y/n- ");
                    fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", &rep);
            (rep=='y')?({goto prime;}):({goto main;});
                }

        }
    case 5:
        {
            mul:
            {
                a=1;
            printf("Value of repetitions- ");
            scanf("%d", &num);
            printf("Enter Digits to multiply:\n");

            for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &b);
                printf("* ");
                a=a*b;
                continue;
            }
            printf("\nThe Multiplication of Digits= %d\n\n", a);
            printf("Repeat? y/n- ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", &rep);
            (rep=='y')?({goto mul;}):({goto main;});
            }
        }
//Case 6 is only for aesthetic reasons.
        case 6:
        printf("\n\nPress Enter\n\n");
}
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile at all. `(rep=='y')?({goto fact;}):({goto main;});` is incorrect C, it should be `if (rep == 'y') 
          goto fact; 
        else
          goto main;`,

Comment: I used it multiple times in code:blocks.  Like at least 10-20 times. It complied smoothly. What error does it report while compiling?

Comment: (rep=='y')?({goto oe;}):({goto main;}); I used this suggestion from stack overflow itself. I was previously using if-else. I wanted to improvise it. And it did work. Let me share you the thread for the same.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272947/goto-not-working-with-operator-in-c

Comment: Exactly, I want to redesign. I felt that I am abusing goto way too much. Can you suggest some improvements, and tips on how to replace the same . Also, I am naive in coding realm. Sorry for the bad code.

Comment: I would say that the first step is to break out the code that does individual jobs (fact, sum, oe, prime, mul etc.) into separate functions. You can then much more easily loop—either within those functions, or by calling them repeatedly. Either way, some variation on `do{work();}while(!done());` will allow you to repeat as often as the user wants.

Comment: Thank You @TimRandall. I will try it and revert back with results tomorrow! Thank You!

Comment: Nobody in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272947/goto-not-working-with-operator-in-c suggests that `(rep=='y')?({goto oe;}):({goto main;})` is a better alternative to `if/else`

Comment: Sorry, but there's so much wrong in this code that it simply isn't salvageable. Not just the goto issue, but also get rid of continue, fflush(stdin), void main, MS DOS libraries, global variables etc etc. And please adopt a consistent indention style with 2 or 4 spaces. Overall, you need a new source of learning C. Your current one (teacher/book) cannot be trusted, they are teaching you bad and incorrect habits.

Comment: This looks too contrived to me to be a genuine piece of code awaiting refactoring. In order to add some context, is this a university exercise?

Comment: I use a book, I am new to coding. Also, I am using global variables because I experienced lag of about 15 seconds in operation. There were two option to stop that problem. Either using global variables or allocating values to it as soon as identifying them (which can be confusing). Thus, global variables. Any other options will be helpful.

Comment: For indentations, I am sorry for that. I have improvised it many times, it became a mess afterwards.  Also, since i am at learning stage, I dont know what to use instead of MS Dos Libraries. Apologies for Bad Code again.

Comment: Already in the linked SO question the top answer states that `goto` and `?:` are different things. One controls execution flow, the other is an operator dealing with expressions. While you **CAN** achieve a `goto` with that operator, you definitely **should not**. **NEVER EVER!**

Comment: @Jabberwocky: your compiler is conformant; the code uses a GCC extension — [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) where the syntax is `({ … })`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the fact that you do not want to change your program in any way other than the goto function, you can put your entire code under a do while loop, a while loop or a for loop like this:

```
do {
....
} while(rep != 'y')
```

Answer (score 4):

A construct can be (outline only):

```
    do {
        printf("\nMAIN MENU\n\n1. Factorial\n2. Sum\n3. Odd/Even\n4. Prime Number\n5. Multiplication\n6. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        switch (n) {
             case 1:
                  do {
                      //do your stuff
                      printf("repeat?")
                      scanf(" %c", &rep);
                  } while (rep=='y');
                  break;
        }

    } while (n<6);
```

Comment: Thank You! Will revert back with results.

Comment: This changes the program's behaviour - in the original if "repeat?" is affirmed, only the selected operation is repeated, not the main menu.

Comment: @Armali, I see...changed it.

Comment: @Armali The program works like a charm after changing it to do while, keeping the behavior of the program same.

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution to my issue. Replaced the multiple Go-to with do-while loops. 
Thank You for suggestions @Paul Ogilvie and @Harshit Joshi.
Any suggestions regarding improvements in the code are Welcome!

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int a,b,i,num,n;
char rep;
void main (void)

{
    do
    {
        printf("\nMAIN MENU\n\n1. Factorial\n2. Sum\n3. Odd/Even\n4. Prime Number\n5. Multiplication\n6. Exit\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        switch(n)
        {
            case 1:
 //Replaced Goto from here with do while loop
                do
                {
                    printf("\nNumber- ");
                    scanf("%d", &num);
                    a=1;
                    for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
                        {
                            a=a*i;
                            continue;
                        }
                        printf("\nFactorial of %d= %d\n\n", num, a);
                        printf("Repeat? y/n- ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%c", &rep);
                }
                while(rep=='y');
                break;

            case 2:
                do
                {
                    a=0;
                    printf("\nValue of repetitions- ");
                    scanf("%d", &num);
                    printf("Enter Digits to sum:\n");

                    for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
                    {
                        scanf("%d", &b);
                        if(i<num)
                            printf("+ ");
                        a=a+b;
                    }
                    printf("\nThe Sum of Digits= %d\n\n", a);
                    printf("Repeat? y/n- ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%c", &rep);
                }
                while(rep=='y');
                break;

            case 3:
                do
                {
                    printf("\nEnter a Number- ");
                    scanf("%d", &a);
                    (a%2==0)?(printf("\n%d is an Even Number\n",a)):(printf("\n%d is an Odd number\n", a));
                    printf("\nRepeat? y/n- ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%c", &rep);
                }
                while(rep=='y');
                break;

            case 4:
                do
                {
                    printf("\nEnter a Number- ");
                    scanf("%d",&num);
                    if(num==2)
                        printf("\n\n%d is a Prime Number\n\n", num);

                    for(i=2;i<=num-1;i++)
                    {
                        (num%i==0)?({printf("\n\n%d is Not a Prime Number.\n\n", num);break;}):({printf("\n\n%d is a Prime Number\n\n", num);break;});
                    }
                    printf("\nRepeat? y/n- ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%c", &rep);
                }
                while(rep=='y');
                break;

            case 5:
                do
                {
                    a=1;
                    printf("\nValue of repetitions- ");
                    scanf("%d", &num);
                    printf("Enter Digits to multiply:\n");

                    for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
                    {
                        scanf("%d", &b);
                        printf("* ");
                        a=a*b;
                        continue;
                    }
                    printf("\nThe Multiplication of Digits= %d\n\n", a);
                    printf("Repeat? y/n- ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%c", &rep);
                }
                while(rep=='y');
                break;
        }
    }
    while(rep=='n');
//Used the above given condition to continue the loop in Main Menu as well. Works properly.
}
```

Comment: Consider checking the values returned by the calls to `scanf()`. If the input is not as expected, e.g. a letter is input when a number is expected, no assignment to the variable will be made. This can lead to undefined behavior in some cases, and certainly to unexpected behavior. `scanf()` returns the number of successful assignments made, so after `int ret_val = scanf("%d", &n);` the `ret_val` variable holds 1 if correct input was given, and 0 otherwise (or `EOF` in rarer cases). Also, note that using global variables is a very bad habit, and rarely necessary.